# %%replyemailaddress%% not receiving css styling

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, css

I am creating an email and I want the replyemailaddress token to show. If I have the token as:

```
<a target="_blank" style="color: #150404; text-decoration: none; ">%%=ProperCase(replyemailaddress)=%%</a>
```

I can receive a test email but when I have it as:

```
<a target="_blank" href="%%=ProperCase(replyemailaddress)=%%" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; ">%%=ProperCase(replyemailaddress)=%%</a>
```

The test email doesn't send and I have no styling. What is causing the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your href should have a mailto and no need for propercasing it eg.

```
<a 
target="_blank" 
href="%%[Concat('mailto:', replyemailaddress)]%%" 
style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; ">
%%=ProperCase(replyemailaddress)=%%
</a>
```